# HSQLDB: .data file access denied

Tags: hsqldb, access-denied

I have HSQLDB database which i was unable to open. 
SQL client throws following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: error in script file line: 32 file input/output errorerror c:\db\mydb.data (Access is denied) opening file - file c:\db\mydb.data
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Util.java:380)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Util.java:103)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(JDBCConnection.java:3303)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(JDBCDriver.java:321)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(JDBCDriver.java:259)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:214)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:73)
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.hsqldb.connection.HSQLDBJDBCConnectionFactory.createConnection(HSQLDBJDBCConnectionFactory.java:35)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: error in script file line: 32 file input/output errorerror     c:\db\mydb.data (Access is denied) opening file - file     c:\db\mydb.data
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Error.java:131)
at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readDDL(ScriptReaderText.java:151)
at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderBase.readAll(ScriptReaderBase.java:65)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processScript(Log.java:759)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Log.java:159)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.openPersistence(Logger.java:288)
at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Database.java:218)
at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Database.java:185)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(DatabaseManager.java:240)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(DatabaseManager.java:157)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(JDBCConnection.java:3281)
... 12 more
```

Line 32 is the first line where data model is being created, it contains **create cached table** statement. What could possibly cause that? Is it curable? **Need to recover data.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Access is denied" generally means you file is readonly, or has already been opened by a different process (for example virus checker). Occasionally windows itself locks the file, which can be unlocked only by restarting the machine.